# Show window frame in SketchFlow WPF application

Tags: wpf, sketchflow

I'm developing a WPF application, and using SketchFlow to prototype the application for the client.  All the screens that I've created so far in SketchFlow only show a white frame inside which my screens appear in the SketchFlow player.  The normal window frame elements (title bar, status bar, etc) are missing.  How can I add these in?

Comment: What kind of Mockup control are you using? Is it WindowMockup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might answer your question: [Window like control in SketchFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951573/window-like-control-in-sketchflow)

There's no window-like control in Sketchflow. Basically, you have to do it from scratch.

Comment: I thought I might have to do that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are some nice mockup style controls included in Blend 4 as a sample, one of them is a Window mockup (the one eibhrum mentioned above I believe).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2010/05/13/how-to-add-mockup-controls-to-your-expression-blend-library.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0